Snowflake CREATE ICEBERG TABLE fails with inscrutable error
in Snowflake trying to execute CREATE ICEBERG TABLE for an externally managed Iceberg table fails with the below error

Processing aborted due to error 300010:3780518612; incident 1407480.

CREATE OR REPLACE ICEBERG TABLE <table_name>
    CATALOG = 'POLARIS_CATALOG' -- REST catalog
    EXTERNAL_VOLUME = '<s3_external_volume>' -- s3 bucket
    CATALOG_TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>'
    CATALOG_NAMESPACE = '<table_namespace>;


I've learned from Snowflake support that this error means that the s3 bucket used to define the EXTERNAL VOLUME contains a dot (.).
this is stated in both the Snowflake External Volume (S3) docs and AWS S3 docs, but you wouldn't ever know this from the error message sure isn't helpful!
I've heard from Snowflake that they plan to make the error message more descriptive.
